# Order reversed in Aggregate LINQ query

Tags: linq, aggregate

I think the result should contain [1,1,2,2,3,3] but it contains [3,3,2,2,1,1]. Why is the list being reversed?

```
var sequence = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = sequence.Aggregate(
            Enumerable.Empty<int>(),
            (acc, s) => Enumerable.Repeat(s, 2).Concat(acc));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every item in the sequence, you are concatenating the repetition to the beginning of the accumulated sequence.  Swap the order so you are concatenating to the end.

```
(acc, s) => acc.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s, 2))
```

---

On a side note, it would be easier (and more efficient) to do this to get that sequence instead.

```
var result =
    from s in sequence
    from x in Enumerable.Repeat(s, 2)
    select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way to achieve by using `SelectMany`:

```
 var sequence = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
 var result = sequence.SelectMany(i => new[] {i, i}).ToArray();
```